# How can I define a variable in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, variables

I have the following two buttons in XAML:

```
<Button Content="Previous"
        Margin="10,0,0,10"/>
<Button Content="Next"
        Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
```

How can I define "10" to be a variable so I can change it in one place, something like this:

**PSEUDO CODE:**

```
<variable x:key="theMargin"/>
<Button Content="Previous"
        Margin="{Variable theMargin},0,0,{Variable theMargin}"/>
<Button Content="Next"
        Margin="0,0,{Variable theMargin},{Variable theMargin}"/>
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try this:

add to the head of the xamlfile

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then Add this to the resource section:

```
<System:Double x:Key="theMargin">2.35</System:Double>
```

Lastly, use a thickness on the margin:

```
<Button Content="Next">
   <Button.Margin>
      <Thickness Top="{StaticResource theMargin}" Left="0" Right="0"
                  Bottom ="{StaticResource theMargin}" />
   </Button.Margin>
</Button>
```

A lot of system types can be defined this way: int, char, string, DateTime, etc

Note:
You're right... Had to do some better testing.. changed to code so that it should work

Comment: hmmm, I add <System:Double x:Key="theMargin">2.35</System:Double>
 in Window.Resources and got "System:Double was not found", added "System" as a reference but didn't help, what am I missing?

Comment: Double doesn't come up in the dropdown, only e.g. "RegistryHive" and three others, I've references System.Core, what else do I have to reference?

Comment: I found my issue: I was adding this xmlns:System="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Win32;assembly=mscorlib" and should have been adding this: xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Comment: This seems more like a constant than a variable to me.  Hard-coded values don't do much for me.

Comment: I had to use a lower-case `'s'` for `System` to make this work.

Answer (score 7):

Similiar to Sorskoot's answer, you can add a thickness resource to use, thereby defining each margin direction independently

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="myMargin" Top="5" Left="10" Right="10" Bottom ="5"></Thickness>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then just use the Thickness as the Margin:

```
<Button Content="Next" Margin="{StaticResource myMargin}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try adding the value as a [`StaticResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx)?

```
Resources.Add("theMargin", 10);
```

Then you can get that value like this:

```
<Button Content="Previous"
        Margin="{StaticResource theMargin},0,0,{StaticResource theMargin}"/>
<Button Content="Next"
        Margin="0,0,{StaticResource theMargin},{StaticResource theMargin}"/>
```

Comment: I added Resources.Add("theMargin", 50); after InitializeComponent in my code behind, but XAML couldn't access it.

Comment: The text ',0,0,{StaticResource theMargin}' is not allowed after the closing '}' of a MarkupExtension expression

Answer (score 1):

You need invoke this before InitializeComponent or use INotifyPropertyChanged Interface after that

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core @Sorskoot's answer was working, but produced a warning. So instead I used this namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
```