# Problems when specifying constant double values in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I work on a German system. In a ResourceDictionary I try to define a double constant

```
<system:Double x:Key="RotationPointX">0.5</system:Double>
```

When I use here a point, so I get an error in the XAML: "Input string was not in a correct format". When I use a comma:

```
<system:Double x:Key="RotationPointX">0,5</system:Double>
```

I get no error in the XAML, but a runtime error. Because 0,5 is not recognized as a valid double value.

I tried to solve this problem by specifying the language with xml:lang="en-US", but that has not helped. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/a/877330/754438

Comment: what do you mean by "I get an error in the XAML"? is it a compilation error or designer error? In the runtime, the sting is parsed by the application culture. in design time - parsing is according to VS culture.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss anything? I just tried on an Italian regional settings, and works fine using the dot (i.e. the invariant-settings). Could you detail how do you use that constant?

Comment: ShayD it is a designer error, not a compilation eror. It is perhaps negligible, but I would like to solve this problem.

Comment: Mario, All essential information that might be needed for a possible solution, I have already indicated.

Comment: @peter70 Okay, but how is used the constant? Is it read by the underlying code (e.g. C#), or is used as "StaticResource" within the XAML?

Comment: It is used as StaticResource in same file: ResourceDictionary->ControlTemplate->Grid. How it is used, but plays no role at all! The error does not occur there on where it is used, but only where it is defined. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort!