# Define a Thickness using resources

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

In a windows UWP app project, I am trying to define a Thickness by assigning to its `Left`, `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom` properties:

```
<Setter Property="Margin">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Thickness Left="{StaticResource SomeDouble}"
                   Top="0"
                   Right="0"
                   Bottom="0" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/877330/570336) seems to suggest that this is possible in WPF, however, in my UWP project (as well as in a WinRT app), I get the following error:

```
XAML Thickness type cannot be constructed. 
In order to be constructed in XAML, a type cannot be abstract, interface, nested, generic 
or a struct, and must have a public default constructor.
```

Is there a way to define the Thickness using resources?

Answer (score 11):

<strike>You still can. Only to change `System:Double` to `x:Double`. e.g.</strike>

<strike>`<x:Double x:Key="SomeDouble">12</x:Double>`</strike>

### Update

Interesting, with the above xaml the designer shows up fine but it doesn't compile... Yes it gives the exact same error like you showed.

So I guess you have to define the whole `Thickness` in xaml.

```
<Thickness x:Key="Thickness1">12,0,0,0</Thickness>

<Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource Thickness1}" />
```

I ran the project this time and yeah it worked. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did, yet it produces the error I gave above...?