# Can you define a Thickness static resource in UWP XAML that references another static resource (double) for one of its values?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to define a double that will always be the left margin value in two difference Thickness values, both of which will be used in multiple places.  E.g.:

```
<x:Double x:Key="BreadcrumbElementLeftMargin">23</x:Double>

<Thickness x:Key="BreadcrumbTextElementMargin">(reference value 23 above),20,0,0</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="BreadcrumbImageElementMargin">(reference value 23 above),40,0,0</Thickness>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in UWP because in UWP Thickness has no default constructor so the Left, Top, Right and Bottom properties cannot be set individually.

Side note:
In WPF this can be done like this:

```
<x:Double x:Key="BreadcrumbElementLeftMargin">23</x:Double>

<Thickness x:Key="BreadcrumbTextElementMargin"
           Bottom="0"
           Left="{StaticResource BreadcrumbElementLeftMargin}"
           Right="0"
           Top="20" />

<Thickness x:Key="BreadcrumbImageElementMargin"
           Bottom="0"
           Left="{StaticResource BreadcrumbElementLeftMargin}"
           Right="0"
           Top="40" />
```

Comment: I just tried this and got this error: XamlCompiler error WMC0100: XAML Thickness type cannot be constructed. In order to be constructed in XAML, a type cannot be abstract, interface, nested, generic or a struct, and must have a public default constructor.  This suggests doing this is not possible in UWP? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149204/define-a-thickness-using-resources