# Android namespace constants like in WPF

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

In WPF, XAML files can contain  tag which contains constants that can be bound to views. Is there something similar in android?

I know I can define constants in **res/values**/some_file.xml. This is good when I need to reuse contants across multiple layouts but not in case, when I need to use some constants exclusively by single layout.

Also I know about **data-binding** in which we can define `<data>` in layout scope, but it requires to wrap layout in `<layout>` tag and also to inflate layout in specific way via `DataBindUtil` class. Moreover, using data-binding to bind constants looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

Android has the concept of custom view classes that can contain custom attributes that a developer can define. Take a look a [Define Custom Attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) in the documentation.

> To add a built-in View to your user interface, you specify it in an XML element and control its appearance and behavior with element attributes. Well-written custom views can also be added and styled via XML. To enable this behavior in your custom view, you must:
>
> Define custom attributes for your view in a  resource element
>      Specify values for the attributes in your XML layout
>      Retrieve attribute values at runtime
>      Apply the retrieved attribute values to your view

Is this the type of thing you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for something like static binding (constants are defined directly in layout and used by this layout in different places), here is an example: [WPF static binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877304/how-can-i-define-a-variable-in-xaml#answer-877330). If you work with android for a long time, and you know there is no such thing, you can edit answer and I can mark it as accepted, since I could not find something about it so it seems it is not supported.

Comment: I understand. I have not seen anything like that but, IMO, it would be useful. A quick search around shows similar questions with the suggestions you have already identified. That is not to say that there is not some clever way to make it happen. My concern is that it would be non-standard. I can't prove the negative, so I will be interested to see if anyone has a good solution.