# XAML Syntax for Resource Double value

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to define a static resource to be used for FontSize for multiple items, but I'd like to apply it to the page in which I'm defining it, so I have:

```
<Page x:Class="Sample1.JoggingPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample1">
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <core:Double x:Key="MainFontSize">28</core:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.FontSize>
  What do I have to do here to use MainFontSize as the value??
</Page.FontSize>
```

I have tried everything I can think of and searched for a related answer, but I obviously don't have the important keywords to search for this.

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Comment: `<StaticResource ResourceKey="MainFontSize"/>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/877330/3225

Comment: @kenny That was not the question.

Comment: @Chris You would usually declare the resource in App.xaml and just reference it by `FontSize="{StaticResource MainFontSize}"` in the Page.

Comment: @Clemens which is also in the answer I referenced.

Comment: @kenny Read the question again, carefully.

Comment: Clemens' answer is correct. Maybe a main font size ought to go in a resource dictionary which is merged in app.xaml. You would then just be able to do FontSize="{StaticResource MainFontSize}" inside the page tag. DynamicResource in the page tag would also avoid the problem I guess you hit when referencing a resource declared in page.resources.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you. That was the syntax I was looking for! I actually tried typing that in, but intellisense didn't show it as an option, so I assumed it was incorrect syntax (too reliant on intellisense!). So, if you put something in the app's resources, you can simply access it from anywhere in the app without having to merge it?

Comment: Yes, exactly...