# How do i use a given static resource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-5

I have a WPF code behind like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(string url)
    {
        Resources.Add("url", url);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now i have the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WayFair_Label_App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WayFair_Label_App"
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel>
    <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"
                  Source="{StaticResource url}"
    />
</DockPanel>
```

So i try to use the given url string as source in webview2 as static resource.

Currently it says "Resource 'url' is not found". But why? How can i get this working?
I got this idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877304/how-can-i-define-a-variable-in-xaml).

Comment: InitializeComponent certainly rewrites the Resources collection. Remove the Source assignment from XAML and write `webView.Source = url;` after InitializeComponent.

Comment: Should work if you add the resource before calling `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: Or add a public `Url` property to your MainWindow class and bind the Source property like `Source="{Binding Url, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`

Comment: Yeah, webView.Source = url works. But the other option to use a property i will keep in mind.

Comment: Resources is primarily intended for storing templates, converters, styles, colors, and other objects not related to your presentation logic. I would not recommend using resources to store primitive types.

Comment: @AndrewH Is it? Can you provide any reference document where that is stated?